# Unable to right click

Tags: menu, appearance

It appears I cannot right click on the menus to change their appearance etc, nothing happens. I am completely new to Linux so might be doing something wrong. Installed Utweakgi, but it tells me system or administrator cannot use the software and might not load.

Can someone help me with this one, don't know where else to look.

Comment: What do you get when you right click on your panel??

Comment: I tried, works perfectly. Showing context menu.

Answer (score 1):

It's Difficult to tell what exactly it is you want to change but. If you want to change the menus in ubuntu there are three places that will be of use.

1. Administration > Appearance this is where you can change your theme, wallpaper and effects you can also change icons and other settings by clicking on the modify button while choosing a theme. This will create a new modified theme so you can always go back to the default.
2. Administartion > Main Menu here you can change what programs are shown and not shown. and you can also change the position of icons in the menu. Or create your own menu
3. And right clicking on the top of a menu the part on the panel/bar will give you the option of removing the menu (remember to check the name of the menu first which will be in the "about" section of the right click menu.

Hope these give give you a basic understanding of how to modify the interface to your own liking there are millions of options, tweeks and mods for ubuntu but its best to start small and know how to get back something before you hit that delete key.

Happy trails

Comment: This doesn't really answer the "unable to right click" in general question